# Access Junction Table SQL

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

First and foremost, thank you for your time in reviewing my post and offering your advice. I have a database with the following schema:

```
tblPR:
PRID
Title
Amount
Status

tblProgram:
ProgramID
ProgramCode
ProgramTitle

tblFund:
FundCodeID
FundCode
FundTitle
```

There’s a many to many relationship between the previous two tables. Therefore, I setup a junction table.

```
tblPrgFund:
ProgramCode
ProgramTitle
FundCode
FundTitle
```

(These are lookup fields to their respective tables so I believe Access pulls their key as well which would be the ids)

Now main form is set to tblPR and subform is set to tblPrgFund. There are two comboboxes in subform for FundTitle and ProgramTitle respectively. Requirement is to filter ProgramTitle based upon FundTitle that is selected by user.

To do this I tried the following SQL command in VBA for gotfocus event of program title combo box. But it is only displaying ProgramID and not ProgramTitle. I don’t even think the ids are correct tbh.

```
"SELECT ProgramID, ProgramTitle FROM tblPrgFund WHERE FundCode = " & Me.FundCode
```

Comment: Set the combobox ColumnCount and ColumnWidth properties. Your field names have a space. Enclose with [ ]. Should avoid spaces in naming convention.

Comment: Sorry I cleared my original post so it’s clear of the actual field names.

Comment: That approach makes no sense. The subform is to create records in tblPrgFund. How can you filter Program based on Fund if the combination doesn't exist yet? The subform should have Master/Child link with main form on the PRID and ProgramID fields (the primary and foreign keys) then only 1 combobox to select FundID. tblPrgFund should save only the ID values and then build queries joining tables to retrieve related data.

Comment: I am thinking tblPR and tblProgram should be combined. tblPrgFund would be a related child table.

Comment: I wish I could just share the dB but I cannot unfortunately. The sub form is another junction table. I’ve actually called that tblJunction. The master is tblPR. Nonetheless I’m looking for a SQL statement that allows me to filter the values of a combobox (rowsource property) that selects from tblPrgFund to only the choices where fundcode matches the user choice of another combobox in the same sub form. I’m not sure why what I’ve written doesn’t work.

Comment: Your narrative said the subform is bound to tblPrgFund. If this is not the case, then correct the narrative. No new info so my comments unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your dilemma correctly, you want something like this:

```
"SELECT ProgramTitle FROM tblPrgFund WHERE FundTitle = " & Me.FundCode
```

OR (if you wanted to use the `FundCode`, and not the `FundTitle`)

```
"SELECT ProgramTitle FROM tblPrgFund WHERE FundCode = " & Me.FundCode
```

NOTE: This assumes that your `FundCode` and `FundTitle` are **unique values** in your data. But you shouldn't be grabbing the `ProgramId`, unless your intention is to use it in some way.

That being said, I would **highly suggest** you use **After Update** instead of **GotFocus** as your event for this type of update. Since this is a drop down box, *I would assume* you don't want the updates to go just from the initial selection of the Combo Box, but rather start after a selection has been made.

Comment: If I just have ProgramTitle, the drop down is blank. Also FundCode is not unique. Multiple FundCodes can share a Program, and multiple programs can share a fund code.

Comment: So.. if I have this straight, you're populating the ComboBox with the **GotFocus** event? Oof. I went the wrong direction with this one. The **After Update** event is intended for the finalization of the drop down box selection. If I was doing this, I would probably have used a Row Source (using a query) to populate the ComboBox. But, based on what you're saying, I think we are going to need more information to fully answer this question. 

Also, if your `FundCode` and `FundTitle` are not unique, then you'll need something to refine the query more than a WHERE statement or a different field.

Comment: So I entered unique fundcode and programtitle in their respective table. I entered their matches / relationships in tblprgfund. So Program 1:Fund A; Program 1:Fund B; Program 2:Fund B.... if it’s ok can we assume gotfocus works appropriately for now.